# NotificationCenter: How to add a notification in BaseController without it being added multiple times?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, notificationcenter

I have a BaseViewController and all the view controllers in my app inherits from this BaseViewController class. I want to listen to a custom notification in some of my view controllers. I added the following code in viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear methods of BaseViewController

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.actOnNotification), name: NSNotification.Name("MyNotification"), object: nil)
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(NSNotification.Name("MyNotification"))
    }
```

My app is designed in such a way that the main page gets loaded after a custom splash view controller and an another view controller (both of these inherit from BaseViewController too). Basically, it is the third view controller in the stack.

Now, the `actOnNotification` method gets called three times when the home page of my app loads. Is there a way that I can have it called only for once, when the home page loads?

It obviously works if I listen to notification directly in home page of the app.

Comment: If you are adding the notification observer in the base class then all instances will observe the notification. As you said,  the solution is to only add the observer in the view controller that needs to observe the notification. Your base class should only include functionality that is common.  If you want to observe the notification in a few controllers then you could add a function to your base class that adds the observer and call that function from the relevant subclass `viewWillAppear`. You can set a Boolean property so that the super 'viewWillDisappear` removes the observer

Comment: Thanks, Hoseinali Alborzi's answer actually helped me solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used a navigationController for mainViewController after that you implement addObserver in navigationController

```
class MainNavigationViewController: UINavigationController {

      override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.actOnNotification), name: NSNotification.Name("MyNotification"), object: nil)
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(NSNotification.Name("MyNotification"))
    }
}
```

Also you can get currentViewcontroller

```
    guard let currentViewcontroller = self.viewControllers.last() else { return}
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case, it was a TabBarController where I ended up doing the above. I have accepted this as the answer.